# How do i prevent Web Response Stream to Close ?

Tags: c#, encoding, httpwebrequest

**Context:**

I am improving my .dll to execute WebRequests (Get and Post), adding a new feature, that is : automatic encoding detecting after the response

**How will it work:**

1. User of the library configures it's default parameters for requests, including Encoding
2. Library executes the request for a certain url
3. Library checks if the encoding of the page is the same as the pre-configured one (via checking the value of the meta tag)
4. If the encodes are not the same, i re-encode the response using the right encoding (the one found on the page)

**Code Fragment:**

```
           // Executes web request and wait for response
            using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse) m_HttpWebRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream ())
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader (stream))
                    {
                        // Reading Stream to the end
                        response = reader.ReadToEnd ();

                        // Identifying the encode used on the page
                        // I will not paste method here, but it works
                        m_PageEncoding = IdentifyEncoding (response);                            
                    }

                    // Checking if the page encode is not the same as the preconfigured one
                    if (m_PageEncoding != System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding (m_encoding))
                    {
                        using (var encodedReader = new StreamReader (stream, m_PageEncoding))
                        {
                            response = encodedReader.ReadToEnd();                                
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Problem:**

Once i create another Reader, which is the `EncodedReader`with the Encoding argument, an exception is thrown: `Stream was not readable`.

If, i nest the readers within the responseStream using block, the response value after the second reading is always "empty"

```
using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream ())
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader (stream))
                    {
                        // Reading Stream to the end
                        response = reader.ReadToEnd ();

                        // Identifying the encode used on the page
                        m_PageEncoding = IdentifyEncoding (response);

                        // Checking if the page encode is not the one i've used as argument
                        if (m_PageEncoding != System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(m_encoding))
                        {
                            using (var encodedReader = new StreamReader(stream, m_PageEncoding))
                            {
                                response = encodedReader.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                        }                         
                    }
                }
```

**Question:**

How can i execute the ReadToEnd method twice, on the same WebResponse, without executing the request twice, which would be lousy.

Comment: why do you want to read a web request stream twice? That would be slow and you could lose connection in the middle. It isn't much better than executing it twice. Wouldn't it be better to read it once then convert the response string in memory using [Encoding.Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.convert.aspx)?

Comment: Actually, im a bit lost in how the whole process works and which role each class is taking here, would you help me ?

Comment: How about just looking at [HttpWebResponse.ContentEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.contentencoding.aspx) before actually reading the content?

Comment: OK the `HttpWebResponse resp` gives you access to all the info about the response, including http status etc. `stream` is the physical stream to the website which transfers data. `StreamReader` gives you useful methods to do the reading of the stream. So your code is not far off if you remove the `if` block - you just need to do something to convert the `response` variable

Comment: resp.ContentEncoding = ""